# Apply Style only to input=text

Tags: html, css

I have CSS code like this

```
div ul li input{ width:70%}
```

What to do if I want this style applicable **Only to the input elements of type=text** ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an attribute selector

```
div ul li input[type=text] { width: 70%; }
```

Comment: Probably no surprise to anyone, but just a note that this won't work with IE6.

Comment: @MichaelMior Using a class for the `input` will work in IE6 though, right?

Comment: @Saladin Akara: Yeah but we've wasted enough time doing that for the past 10 years ;)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, yes we have. :)

Comment: This was really simple! Thanks all! Worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 4):

```
div ul li input[type=text]
{ 
    width:70%
}
```